# How to make elements stop from moving when resizing the window after using percentage

Tags: html, css

So I have divs that I have within my webpage .. like header , or div boxes .. they adjust fine on bigger screen sizes so that they dont look too tiny on a big monitor , but the issue is that when I resize the window or browser to make it small , all the elements move along till they reach a point where they all meet and it gets ugly .. How can I make it so the divs I have adjust to bigger screen sizes becoming bigger as well , but then stop them from moving along with the window when resizing the window making it smaller ???  I used percentages from all the elements I want to readjust and make bigger on bigger /wider screens

Below is an example of my code .. my header and other elements with these classes move to the point where they overlap when resizing the window

```
.header{
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        left:0;
        background:#EB6A4A; 
    }

    .slogan{
        position:absolute;
        top:60%;
        left:40.5%;
    }

    .login{
        position:absolute;
        top:15%;
        left:90%;
    }

        .whitebackground{
        background:#FFFFFF;
    }
```

Comment: you can set min-width or min-height for the small resize problem, and there is floated element on your page?

Comment: @Dvir Ok .. so the min-width and min-height will prevent the css elements from moving even though the width was given in percentage ?

Comment: no. It's will set the minimum width size and height.
But if there are float elements they will still move.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question because you didn't post any code but i think that your solution can be using css style:

```
max-width:50%;
min-width:800px;
max-height:500px;
min-height:21%;
```

properties in pecentage or pixel as you prefer, so you can tell divs how much expand and how much get smaller.

Hope it helps, if you post your code maybe i can be more useful.

Regards

EDIT 1:

This should resolve your problem:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;

}
.header{
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        top:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        left:0;
        background:#EB6A4A; 
    }

    .slogan{
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        top:60%;
        left:40.5%;
    }

    .login{
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        top:15%;
        left:90%;
    }

        .whitebackground{
        background:#FFFFFF;
    }
```

Just do the same with the class you didn't poste in css. The idea is having all items with position relative and floated on the left so they don't move. Should work!

Comment: So if I do it the way you suggested using percentages with min-height and max-height , they will not move when I make the window really small ?

Comment: If you use min-width and min-height in pixel you give a minimum size they can reach. Unless that they will not resize. I think you need it but until you don't post code i can't effectively understand what you need!
Post your css!

Comment: Please can you give me a +1 for answer? server blocked my questions and i really need to post one for my problem! thanks!

Comment: I edited my question and posted the code ... could you please check it out ... basically the header and other elements move and overlap when the window becomes too small after resizing it